# when I class a div and assign css to that class it doesn't do anything

Tags: html, css

Sorry, I'm relatively new to programming. My question is, is that I have the div classed as `.logo`, so when I go over to my css file, I want to assign some different dimensions to the gif, as you can see in the css snippet, but the thing is that it just doesn't work...

Html markup

```
<div class="logo">
    <img src="giphy.gif">
</div>
```

CSS styles

```
.logo {
  width: 333px;
  height: 396px;
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code dump site. What steps have you tried to solve this problem? Please review [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I'm sorry, i'll try to explain better next time, but thanks, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than assigning the class to the img as suggested by @leelum1- simply add the element to the existing style rule.

The reason why this is a better approach is that other styling might need to be done on the div that currently has the logo class and it is better add specificity to your selectors than trying to make the elements classes fit the selector. Also, don't forget to self close the img element and to add an alt tag for accessibility.

```
<div class="logo">
  <img src="giphy.gif"  alt="logo image" />
 </div>

.logo img {
  width: 333px;
  height: 396px;
}
```

Alternatively you can add the attributes to the img element directly. The advantage of this is that the browser will apply these during the rendering process and so will 'reserve' a space in the DOM with those dimensions. This is the more semantically correct approach.

```
<div class="logo">
  <img src="giphy.gif" width="333" height="396" alt="logo image" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because your img is not constrained by the div. Try adding the class to the img instead

```css
.logo {
  width: 333px;
  height: 396px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img class="logo" src="giphy.gif">
</div>
```